# Capturar parte de uma string dentro de um par de caracteres <> usando regex

Tags: java, regex

Estou tentando resolver um problema que consiste em trocar palavras que estejam entre `<>`.

Por exemplo, tenho a seguinte string: `<><PALAVRA outrapalavra>palavra</PALAVRA>`

Além dessa string, recebo um parâmetro que indica qual ou quais palavras na string devo trocar por um valor `x` e o *case-sensitive* entre as palavras deve ser ignorado.

No caso do exemplo, `PALAVRA` e `palavra` são iguais entre si e ao parâmetro, `outrapalavra` difere das duas e do parâmetro e não deve ser alterada. Devo trocar apenas `< PALAVRA >` e `</ PALAVRA >` que estão justamente entre os caracteres **`<>`** e **`</>`**.

Tentei com a seguinte expressão `<(?parâmetro.*?)>` mas não tive sucesso pois ao executar são removidos os `<>` e tudo que está entre `<>` é capturado.

Se fosse só comparar o parâmetro com as palavras já teria resolvido, porém com a restrição de ter que ignorar o *case-sensitive* não achei outra solução que não fosse usar **regex** para encontrar a palavra alvo independente dos caracteres que a compõe serem *maiúsculos* ou *minúsculos*.

Alguém tem alguma dica?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tente assim :

```
String s = "<><PALAVRA outrapalavra>palavra</PALAVRA>";
String parametro = "palavra";
String replace = "NovaPalavra";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<(/?)(.*?)"+parametro+"(.*?)>", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
s = p.matcher(s).replaceAll("<$1$2"+replace+"$3>");

System.out.print(s);
```

O `replace` funciona assim :

- `<` captura literal
- `/` caso tenha
- `.*?` qualquer coisa, o menos possível
- `parametro` palavra a ser substituída
- `.*?` qualquer coisa, o menos possível
- `>` captura literal

[Veja no Ideone.](https://ideone.com/lMGkVx)

Comment: Perfeita a sua solução Guilherme. Era isso mesmo que eu estava tentando fazer, porém eu estava falhando em alguns detalhes que não sabia até então. Obrigado pela ajuda. Como procedo para encerrar o tópico?

Comment: @LucasOliveira a pergunta é dada como encerrada, quando ele tem um resposta aceita, contudo não quer disser que você possa receber novas notificações, ela só deixa de aparecer no feed.